# Manipulating indices in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, reindex

The problem:
I want to shift the index by adding 2  (index+=2) to match it with the indices of a .csv file.

I have a dataframe which looks as follows:

|  | Counts | Counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7 | 10951.0 | 870.0 |
| 8 | 8653.0 | 1772.0 |
| 19 | 28598.0 | 37608.0 |
| 20 | 115266.0 | 123491.0 |
| 21 | 73097.0 | 145261.0 |

my desired result would look like this:

|  | Counts | Counts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 10951.0 | 870.0 |
| 10 | 8653.0 | 1772.0 |
| 21 | 28598.0 | 37608.0 |
| 22 | 115266.0 | 123491.0 |
| 23 | 73097.0 | 145261.0 |

Thanks for the help and sorry if there is anything wrong with my question.

This function:

```
shifted_df.index = pd.Index(range(2, len(shifted_df) + 2))
```

is the first one which as actually changing the index of my dataframe but it just overwrites the given index with the numbers 2 to len(shifted_df)

Comment: simply `df.index += 2`? Do you want to modify in place of create a new DataFrame?

Comment: I want to modify in place but there seems to be a TypeError. yet thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify your `shifted_df` DataFrame in place:

```
shifted_df.index += 2
```

If you want to create a new DataFrame, and assuming `df` the original DataFrame use [`set_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_axis.html):

```
shifted_df = df.set_axis(df.index+2)
```

Or [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html):

```
shifted_df = df.rename(lambda x: x+2)
```

Output:

```
          col1      col2
9      10951.0     870.0
10      8653.0    1772.0
21     28598.0   37608.0
22    115266.0  123491.0
25      1599.0    4536.0
27     61142.0   46921.0
...
1302  117695.0  108044.0
```

Comment: thanks for the help but I get a TypeError:   Exception has occurred: TypeError int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a real number, not 'Index'. The Type of the index seems to be: <class 'pandas.core.indexes.base.Index'> so I can't add 2

Comment: please provide the output of `df.head().to_dict()` assuming `df` your DataFrame

Comment: >>print(added_region_names.head().to_dict())
{'RegionCellCount': {7: 729.1193181818181, 8: 1485.056818181818, 19: 31518.06818181818, 20: 103493.87784090909, 21: 121738.6221590909}}

Comment: @philiVanilli25 this small sample show correct numbers. What about `added_region_names.index[pd.to_numeric(added_region_names.index, errors='coerce').isna()]`?

Comment: Its still the same output, but thanks for the help !

Comment: This wasn't a fix but a question to debug. What is the output of `added_region_names.index[pd.to_numeric(added_region_names.index, errors='coerce').isna()]`? If this gives an empty Index then I don't see where your issue could come from. If this gives non numeric data then we'll see what we can do

Comment: I tried the lambda function you provided as well: Exception has occurred: TypeError
can only concatenate str (not "int") to str. This is the error I got

Comment: Index(['RegionCellCount'], dtype='object')   thats the output of: 
     added_region_names.index[pd.to_numeric(added_region_names.index, errors='coerce').isna()]

Comment: I refactored the code and applyed the first functioned you mentioned above and it worked. Thanks for the help !